# How to parse an array object on Object Mapper for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I got this *JSON* object that I'm trying to parse with ***ObjectMapper*** without success.

[image]

That's how I configure the object that conforms to '*Mappable*' on *Swift*:

[image]

But the object received arrives empty:

[image]

Wha am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: where you can call mapping?

Comment: Share source code as text, do not use images for sample codes.

Comment: Can you show us the original JSON string?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was an array of *Double* what I was looking for. I checked it on an JSON online validator and it showed me the type propertly.

Thanks anyway!